# Installing Microsoft Teams for Linux

Tags: firefox, centos-7, cookies, microsoft-teams, vivaldi

I am looking for *any* way to get Teams working on my Linux installation. It is CentOS 7, with Vivaldi and Firefox.

I have tried both the `.rpm` and the `.deb` files but discovered that an update to Teams made an (reportedly unnecessary) dependency on a c++ compiler that isn't going to work with  7, as per [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/3033/installing-microsoft-teams-in-linux.html) unresolved forum issue.

I reverted to the snap installation, however this appears to have a browser dependency and talks about enabling browser permissions. Surfing to teams.microsoft.com yields the same result in a browser, however it is possible to watch the login loop to failure - in both Firefox and Vivaldi. The [Microsoft documentation site](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/microsoftteams/troubleshoot/teams-sign-in/sign-in-loop#resolution) discusses exactly this issue and the path to resolution in Vivaldi (Chrome) and Firefox, but despite only being 28 days old at time of writing, these instructions do not resolve the issue for either browser.

I have looked for older versions of the Teams installer, but cannot find a download link anywhere. Somewhat comically, [this](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-teams/previous-versions-of-ms-teams-for-linux/m-p/2881078) unanswered question on the Microsoft site asks for exactly the same. Attempting to up-vote the question throws me back into the same failed login loop.

What is going wrong with this installation?

**Update:**

Borrowing from [this](https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-install-microsoft-teams-linux-on-ubuntu-and-centos/) how-to and the included URL, I discovered the open repository:

```
https://packages.microsoft.com/yumrepos/ms-teams/
```

which contained `teams-1.4.00.7556-1.x86_64.rpm`. This installed successfully into my system with no dependency issues. The login problem has not however been resolved. Teams as an installaion still fails to log in, and talks about fixing browser settings. Very confusing.

Comment: Not an answer, I know, but I have Teams working with the client installation on an Ubuntu system. The issue may be limited to certain distros?

Comment: What version of teams are you running?

Comment: I'd have to check when I get home, it's not my office machine.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was that nothing in the installation or choice of app, OS or browser was the issue. The login loop is a bug in Microsoft's implementation or admin rights on the office365.com platform. Altering the rights to only include 'global admin', was the ultimate solution (along with using the dated version of Teams from the repository).